# Calling plt.table for a matrix but getting weird plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a matrix that I want to output the information in a plot and not with a color diagram like imshow does.

I have the following code:

```
     plt.table(cellText=correlation_mat,loc='center',colWidths=np.ones(correlation_mat.shape[0])/correlation_mat.shape[0],cellLoc='center',bbox=[0,0,1,1])
```

It outputs the following:

[image]

How can I fix it to output numbers?

Answer (score 0):

They are there, but they are tiny, so I need to increase the fontsize using

```
table = plt.table(...)
```

and using

```
table.set_fontsize(25)
```